# Elemental Set Theory - counterexample Bijection between power set and set of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a proof that $|S| \leq |P(S)|$ with P(S) being the power set of S.

Let $P =  \mathbb{N}$. let $\{m_1, m_2,\cdots, m_k\} \in P(S) $. Then the binary relation (bijection) with an element of $\mathbb{N}$ is:
$n = \sum_{j=1}^{k}2^{m_j} \in \mathbb{N}$.

This should be a valid counterexample for the theorem about the cardinality of the power set and the original set.

Obviously it should be false, however I can't figure out why. Any thoughts?

Comment: $\mathbb N$ also has subsets that aren't finite.

Comment: Indeed you've shown that the set of _finite_ subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable!

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that if the set $\{m_1, ... ,m_k\}$ is not countable, then the argument is not valid?

Comment: Infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ are all countable...but your bijection is not defined on them.  For example, $\mathbb N$ is a subset of itself, but $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^j$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Note:  in the  spirit of your construction, if $S$ is any subset of $\mathbb N$ you might define $f(S)=\sum_{s\in S}2^{-s}$.  This actually is defined for all subsets and it  defines a bijection between $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ and the interval $[0,1]$